# How to call another activity in android when notification received and app is in background

Tags: android, kotlin, notifications, firebase-cloud-messaging

Tried all way but not getting output

```
 var intent = Intent(application, NavigationDrawerActivity::class.java)
 intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP or Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK or Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)
 startActivity(intent)
```

Comment: Should use PendingIntent to open the activity from Notification, Ref this  https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/build-notification#click

Comment: thanks for answer @MuthukrishnanRajendran

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by sending (payload) data message instead of sending Notification.

```
 // Check if message contains a data payload.
if (remoteMessage.getData().size() > 0) {
    Log.d(TAG, "Message data payload: " + remoteMessage.getData());

  sendNotification(remoteMessage.getData().get("message"));
 }
```

[Reference link - https://stackoverflow.com/a/37845174/11201011](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37845174/11201011)